# How to prove $f(x)=5\sqrt{x^4+1}$ is a transcedental function

Tags: polynomials, transcendental-equations

$$
f(x)=5\sqrt{x^4+1}
$$

I know this function is transcedental function which is also not algebraic function, but i'm not sure how to prove this. Thank you for anyone to help.

Comment: What do you think "transcendental function" means?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ satisfies the equation
$$
f(x)^2 - 25x^4 - 25 = 0
$$
which makes it algebraic (not transcendental) by the standard definition given
[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function).
Perhaps you are thinking of a different function.

**Edit:**
$f(x) = \sqrt[5]{x^4 + 1}$ is also algebraic.  In this case,
$$
f(x)^5 - x^4 - 1 = 0
$$

Comment: oh, my bad. The function should be 5th root of x^4+1

Comment: @NewMan-VB That function is *also* algebraic... o.O